# R Shortcut to include all variables with similar name (ie * in Stata)

Tags: r, stata

I was wondering if there was a shortcut or a symbol to include all variables with  a similar name.

For instance, if I have a regression and I have 50 time dummies of the form `year1`, `year2`, `year3` in Stata I can include all of these by writing `year*`.

Is there a similar functionality in R? I know I can do something like `factor(year)` to get the same effect but for a specific reason I need to have many time dummies.

Comment: Can you provide us with a minimal reproducible example? As it is, we don't really know what your data structure is like...

Comment: `names(myData)[grep("year", names(myData))]`  or if you want the actual data `myData[grep("year", names(myData))]`

Answer (score 3):

In R you would use a formula to define which of the dummy variables to include. So, to include year1, year2 and year3 in your model you would create a formula using `paste` and `as.formula`:

```
formula <- as.formula(paste('y ~', paste0('year', 1:3, collapse  = ' + ')))
formula
#y ~ year1 + year2 + year3
lm(formula, data = data)
```

For an `lm` model you could skip the `as.formula` function because the string gets automatically transformed into a formula inside of `lm` but other models require it.

An alternative is to filter your data.frame to include all the variables you would need and then use `y ~ .` as the formula.

Answer (score 3):

A variation on @Lyzander's answer and @G5W's comment, using `reformulate()`:

```
yearvars <- grep("^year",names(myData), value=TRUE)
form <- reformulate(c("othervar1","othervar2",yearvars),response="stuff")
```

The result of `form` will be `stuff ~ othervar1 + othervar2 + year1 + year2 + ...`

```
lm(form, data=myData)
```